# lodash filter object array and group by to create a new array

Tags: javascript, dictionary, grouping, lodash

Below is the main array, i want to group by dept.name and remove all other fields except "e-depid" to single array

Main array

```
  [
    {
      "id": "67",
      "empid": 5,
      "e-depid": "ab",
      "dept": { "name": "Prod" }
    },
    {
      "id": "67",
      "empid": 7,
      "e-depid": "ac",
      "dept": { "name": "Prod" }
    },
    {
      "id": "67",
      "empid": 5,
      "e-depid": "ad",
      "dept": { "name": "mkt" }
    }
  ]
```

Result array

```
  [
    {
      "Prod": { "e-depid": ["ab", "ac"] },
      "mkt": { "e-depid": ["ad"] }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: why do you want an array as result? what have you tried? what does not work?

Comment: I tried 
let deptype =  _.groupBy(mainArry.map((types) => _.pick(types,['dept.name', 'e-depid'])), 'dept.name'); 
Which returns grouped array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be quite clean with a simple [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call.

```js
const
  input = [{ "id": "67", "empid": 5, "e-depid": "ab", "dept": { "name": "Prod" } }, { "id": "67", "empid": 7, "e-depid": "ac", "dept": { "name": "Prod" } }, { "id": "67", "empid": 5, "e-depid": "ad", "dept": { "name": "mkt" } }],

  result = input.reduce((a, { dept: { name }, 'e-depid': e }) => (
    (a[name] || (a[name] = { 'e-depid': [] }))['e-depid'].push(e), a
  ), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Original answer using [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const
  input = [{ "id": "67", "empid": 5, "e-depid": "ab", "dept": { "name": "Prod" } }, { "id": "67", "empid": 7, "e-depid": "ac", "dept": { "name": "Prod" } }, { "id": "67", "empid": 5, "e-depid": "ad", "dept": { "name": "mkt" } }],

  result = input.reduce((a, { dept: { name }, 'e-depid': e }) => (
    (a[name] ??= { 'e-depid': [] })['e-depid'].push(e), a
  ), {})

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you please suggest an alternative for this "(a[name] ??= { 'e-depid': [] })['e-depid'].push(e), a". I am getting an error with "??=" local assignment

Comment: Sure, you can use an OR short circuit instead, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`.transform`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#transform) for getting the wanted result.

If necessary wrap the object in an array.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "67", empid: 5, "e-depid": "ab", dept: { name: "Prod" } }, { id: "67", empid: 7, "e-depid": "ac", dept: { name: "Prod" } }, { id: "67", empid: 5, "e-depid": "ad", dept: { name: "mkt" } }],
    result = _(data)
        .groupBy(o => o.dept.name)
        .transform((o, a, k) => (o[k] ??= {})['e-depid'] = a.map(o => o['e-depid']))
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```